# hook_form_alter #attributes and #disabled

Tags: taxonomy-terms, forms, hooks

I'm using Drupal 7 and Advanced forum.

The users when will create a new topic will be able to select the forum container and forums, but if they select a container, an error will be showed. I want to avoid this by altering that taxonomy options with adding an #attribute or #disabled to specific forum container.

As I inspect the elements, this is the option that I want to change:

`$form['taxonomy_forums']['und']['#options'][334];`

First of all I've tried to test by adding a class for that option like this:

```
$form['taxonomy_forums']['und']['#options'][334]['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('test-class'));
```

but that didn't worked, it simply erases the title of that option.

With #disabled it didn't work too.

From https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attributes

I can see a good example, but also a note:

> Note: If you are altering an existing form via hook_form_alter() or a
>   similar means, be careful with this property! You will probably want
>   to add to the existing array rather than writing over it, so don't
>   follow this usage example exactly.

It's kind a confusing, so how can I add an #attribute or #disabled to option with hook_form_alter?

EDIT: This is a part from my code:

```
<?php
function custom_alter_form_alter (&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   switch ($form_id) {

        case 'forum_node_form';


        $form['taxonomy_forums']['und']['#process'][] = 'custom_alter_process_checkboxes';
        krumo ($form);
        break;
    }

}

function custom_alter_process_checkboxes($element) {
  $element[334]['#attributes']['class'][] = 'test-class';
  $element[334]['#disabled'] = TRUE;
  return $element;
  krumo ($element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes are converted to their individual form elements in [`form_process_checkboxes ()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_process_checkboxes/7), so you'll need a process function:

```
// In the form alter...
$form['taxonomy_forums']['und']['#process'][] = 'MYMODULE_process_checkboxes';

function MYMODULE_process_checkboxes($element) {
  $element[334]['#attributes']['class'][] = 'test-class';
  $element[334]['#disabled'] = TRUE;
  return $element;
}
```

Comment: I've added your code and I can see the #process function in $form['taxonomy_forums']['und'], added the custom function in my module, but It didn't add any attribute to the option.

Comment: Have you confirmed the process function is being called and inspected `$element`, etc? It's not likely I can give you 100% working code, this is just a guide to help you on the way to writing whatever makes sense for your site and setup

Comment: I've edited the main thread. Krumo doesn't show any $element array. BTW the taxonomy is with select list.

Comment: I would guess that `$form['taxonomy_forums']['und']` isn't the right element in that case. Process functions will run for any valid element they're attached to.